# Access denied for user 'tt-rss'@'localhost' after installing tt-rss

Tags: mysql, tt-rss

Just installed Tiny Tiny RSS. Accessing `http://localhost/tt-rss` from the browser brings me the following error:

> Unable to connect to database (as tt-rss to , database ttrss): Access
>   denied for user 'tt-rss'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you access the database from command line? Did you grant priviliges for that user?

Comment: @Rinzwind  Yes. I used `GRANT ALL ON ttrss.* TO 'tt-rss'@'localhost'`

Comment: Just an idea:
The `GRANT ALL ON ttrss.* TO 'tt-rss'@'localhost'` should also include an `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` statement.  
Can you check the hash of the 'tt-rss' user in the 'user' table of 'mysql' database?  
Is it a 16byte or 41byte hash?  
Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html for more info.

Comment: @PavlosG.41byte hash. `show grants;` says `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'tt-rss'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F6DD0C0AC75395CB5BFC12C46B8880CD156B4799' | 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'ttrss'.* TO 'tt-rss'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after installing tt-rss with all the default settings (connecting to the database using unix socket, with "ident" identification).  I was able to fix it by doing the following:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tt-rss`
2. During the ncurses install process I selected `tcp-ip` as the connection method rather than `socket` and specified "localhost" as the server name.
3. Then I told the installer to use `password` authentication rather than `ident`

...and it worked!  I am now able to reach the tt-rss web interface.

I looked really closely to the installer output of one of my installation attempts to use `ident` and saw an error that it is unable to create a local user account, so that's probably why the default options didn't work...

HTH!